# Google Maps Marker Listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been trying to get listeners to function with GMaps but have been having some troubles. At the moment clicking on markers yields the address of the stop but does not call the handler. Also I'm mapping out markers using the directions service in case that might for whatever reason effect event-handling

Initializing...

```
function initialize() {

  latlng            = avgLatLng(load)
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  mapOptions = {
    zoom             : 10,
    center           : {lat : latlng['latitude'], lng : latlng['longitude']},
    disableDefaultUI : true,
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  setMarkers(load);
  calcRoute(load.stops)
}
```

Calculate route...

```
function calcRoute(stops) {
  var markerLocs = [];
  var travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode['DRIVING'];
  for(var i=0; i<stops.length; i++) {
    markerLocs.push({
      location : new google.maps.LatLng(stops[i].latitude, stops[i].longitude), 
      stopover : (i==0 || i==stops.length ? false : true),
    });
  }
  var request = {
    origin: markerLocs[0].location,
    destination: markerLocs[markerLocs.length-1].location,
    waypoints: markerLocs.slice(1, (markerLocs.length-1)),
    travelMode: travelMode,
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

Set markers...

```
function setMarkers(load) {
  for (var i = 0; i < load.stops.length; i++) {
    var markerOptions = {
        position: {'lat' : load.stops[i]['latitude'], 'lng' : load.stops[i]['longitude']},
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: load.stops[i]['city'],
        zIndex: i,
        clickable: false,
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      console.log('mouseover');
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      console.log('mouseover');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trivial error in your code.  In function function setMarkers(load), your markers are configured not to respond to click events:

```
clickable: false,
```

should be:

```
clickable: true,
```

You need to set clickable even to get mouseOver and MouseOut events.